# Swing Timer GUI Nightmare

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, timer

Okay so I tried implementing a timer into the dialogue of this program which pauses for a second before moving on to the next bit of dialogue. When I try this out, java spits out errors o' plenty such as: illegal start of expression, ; expected, .class expected, and reached end of file while parsing. How can I implement the timer so the window doesn't freeze when I try to have the dialogue on the screen for a specific amount of time? And don't tell me Thread.sleep() cause I tried that and all it does is freeze the application.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class RpsNuke extends JFrame
    implements ActionListener
{
  private final char moves[] = {'R', 'P', 'S', 'N'};
  private JRadioButton rock, paper, scissors, nuke;
  private JTextField display;

  public RpsNuke()
  {
    super("Rock, Paper, Scissors, Nuke");

    rock = new JRadioButton("   Rock   ", true);
    paper = new JRadioButton("   Paper  ");
    scissors = new JRadioButton(" Scissors ");
    nuke = new JRadioButton(" Nuke ");
    ButtonGroup rpsButtons = new ButtonGroup();
    rpsButtons.add(rock);
    rpsButtons.add(paper);
    rpsButtons.add(scissors);
    rpsButtons.add(nuke);

    JButton go = new JButton("         Go         ");
    go.addActionListener(this);

    display = new JTextField(25);
    display.setEditable(false);
    display.setBackground(Color.yellow);

    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    c.add(rock);
    c.add(paper);
    c.add(scissors);
    c.add(nuke);
    c.add(go);
    c.add(display);
    if (nuke.isSelected()){
    display.setText("Don't do it man");}
    else {
    display.setText("");}
  }

  /**
   *  returns -1 if the player wins,
   *  0 if it's a tie, and 1 if the computer wins
   */
  private int nextPlay(char computerMove, char playerMove)
  {
    if ((computerMove == 'R'&&playerMove == 'S')||(computerMove == 'S'&&playerMove=='P')||(computerMove=='P'&&playerMove=='R')){
     return 1;}
    else if ((computerMove == 'R'&&playerMove == 'R')||(computerMove=='S'&&playerMove=='S')||(computerMove=='P'&&playerMove=='P')){
     return 0;}
    else if (playerMove == 'N'){
     return 2;}
    return -1;  

  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
  {
    char playerMove, computerMove;
    playerMove = 0;
    if (rock.isSelected()){
      playerMove = 'R';}
    else if (paper.isSelected()){
      playerMove = 'P';}
    else if (scissors.isSelected()){
      playerMove = 'S';}
    else if (nuke.isSelected()){
      playerMove = 'N';}
    int k = (int)(Math.random() * 3);
    computerMove = moves[k];
    int result = nextPlay(computerMove, playerMove);
    String msg = "";
    if (result != 2)
    {msg = "  You said " + makeWord(playerMove) + ", I said " +
                 makeWord(computerMove);
    if (result < 0){

      msg += " -- you win.";}
    else if (result == 0){

      msg += " -- tie.";}
    else if (result > 0){
      msg += " -- I win.";}
    }
    if (result == 2)
    {
     TimerTask tasknew = new TimerScheduleFixedRateDelay();
     Timer timer = new Timer();

      // scheduling the task at fixed rate delay
     timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tasknew,1000,1000);
     @Override
    }
     // this method performs the task

     public void run() {
      msg = "It's too late, we're all dead!";    
      msg = "...";

      msg = "Look at what you did, there's nothing left.";

      msg = "Looks like we have to start over again...";
      window.setVisible(false);
      main(null);                       
    }          
    display.setText(msg);
  }

  private String makeWord(char move)
  {
    String word = "";

    switch (move)
    {
      case 'R': word = "rock"; break;
      case 'P': word = "paper"; break;
      case 'S': word = "scissors"; break;
      case 'N': word = "nuke"; break;
    }
    return word;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) //Here
  {
    RpsNuke window = new RpsNuke();
    window.setBounds(300, 300, 400, 140);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);
  }
} //And here
```

Comment: and the errors aplenty are .......

Comment: @KevinDTimm I edited it so the errors are shown

Comment: This is probably nothing more than a careless error. Have you counted your curly braces? Do all opening braces have expected matching closing braces? I think that you're likely leaving one or two out.

Comment: Also, don't use a java.util.Timer with a Swing application. Use a javax.swing.Timer also known as a Swing Timer. Else you will easily have threading issues.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be the start of your problems...

```
if (result == 2) {
    TimerTask tasknew = new TimerScheduleFixedRateDelay();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    // scheduling the task at fixed rate delay
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tasknew, 1000, 1000);
    @Override
}

public void run() {
```

There's no such class called `TimerScheduleFixedRateDelay`, `Timer` doesn't have a default constructor, you don't seem to have declared `tasknew` and I have no idea why `@Override` appears here...

Let's start by commenting those out for the moment

```
if (result == 2) {
    //TimerTask tasknew = new TimerScheduleFixedRateDelay();
    //Timer timer = new Timer();
    // scheduling the task at fixed rate delay
    //timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tasknew, 1000, 1000);
    //@Override
}

public void run() {
```

The next problem is you're missing a closing bracket...

```
if (result == 2) {
    ...
 }

 // Something is amiss here...

public void run() {
```

It should look more like...

```
    if (result == 2) {
        ...
     }

}

public void run() {
```

Next...

```
public void run() {
    msg = "It's too late, we're all dead!";
    msg = "...";

    msg = "Look at what you did, there's nothing left.";

    msg = "Looks like we have to start over again...";
    window.setVisible(false);
    main(null);
}

display.setText (msg);
```

`msg` is undefined, `window` is undefined and `main` is undefined and `display.setText` is being callout outside of a method context, which is illegal...

```
public void run() {
    String msg = "It's too late, we're all dead!";
    msg = "...";

    msg = "Look at what you did, there's nothing left.";

    msg = "Looks like we have to start over again...";
    display.setText (msg);
    //window.setVisible(false);
    //main(null);
}
```

It's easy enough to fix the `msg`, not sure about the `display.setText`, but since it's taking `msg`, I assume it belongs in the `run` method and I have no idea about `window` and `main` still needs to be resolved...

Which leads us onto...

```
}

private String makeWord(char move)
  {
    String word = "";

    switch (move)
    {
      case 'R': word = "rock"; break;
      case 'P': word = "paper"; break;
      case 'S': word = "scissors"; break;
      case 'N': word = "nuke"; break;
    }
    return word;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) //Here
  {
    RpsNuke window = new RpsNuke();
    window.setBounds(300, 300, 400, 140);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);
  }
} //And here
```

Oh, I think I found where our missing brace went to....This means that everything below the `}` the first brace in the above code is actually being defined outside of the `class`, which, for the context of this question, is illegal...

So, lets comment that out...

```
//}

private String makeWord(char move)
  {
    String word = "";

    switch (move)
    {
      case 'R': word = "rock"; break;
      case 'P': word = "paper"; break;
      case 'S': word = "scissors"; break;
      case 'N': word = "nuke"; break;
    }
    return word;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) //Here
  {
    RpsNuke window = new RpsNuke();
    window.setBounds(300, 300, 400, 140);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);
  }
} //And here
```

There, things look a "little" better...I also think I found `window`, but it's being defined in `main`...not very helpful ;)

Based on look at your code, I think you should avoid `java.util.Timer` and use `javax.swing.Timer` instead, this will prevent you from updating the UI from outside the content of the Event Dispatching Thread which is just another cup of worms you would probably wish to avoid...

Comment: +1 wow, I had started to write an answer but hadn't planned anything this thorough. Good that I was slow enough.

Comment: @kiheru Not sure if I caught everything, so if you have anything else to add don't hesitate to put another answer together, it was a real mess so I'm likely to have missed something :P

Comment: Not really much to add. The `@Override` and `public void run()` were likely parts of the `TimerTask`, that somehow got scattered a bit around (and called by a constructor that does not exist). But as said, the OP should not be using `java.util.Timer` anyway.